# Rename all files in a folder to consecutive numbers

Tags: command-line, rename

I would like to rename all files in a folder so to have consecutive numbers. For instance:

```
1.png
2.png
3.png
etc
```

I know there is the rename command and I know there are **DOZENS** of similar questions in here but I can't find the way.

**NOTE**: Suggested duplicate doesn't contain a solution specific for my case. Please stop flagging this as duplicate, because suggested duplicate does not answer my question

Comment: Which file will be `1.png`? Shell globbing order?

Comment: @heemayl I don't really understand what you mean but the 1.png I want to be the first file in the folder.

Comment: @Adam He's asking how you have the files sorted. The shell sorts them one way according to name, but you might want them sorted by last modified date, a different way by name, etc.

Comment: You might want to provide example of how files are named in the folder.  This can be easily done, but we need to know what the original filenams will be.

Comment: @wjandrea Oh I want them sorted based on their name i.e. 1 first 2 second etc...

Comment: @Serg The files are named with the default name of the Screenshot software of Ubuntu.

Comment: Ok , let me sketch up a small script, i'll post it in about 20 mins or so

Comment: By the way , what if the folder contains subfolders ? Leave those alone or give it a number as well ?

Comment: Posted answer, please review

Comment: **CLOSE-VOTERS**:  as shown in the comments,  OP specifically stated that he tried the suggested duplicate and it did not work. Please retract your votes.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194479/295160

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you want to follow the shell globbing order while sorting files, you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash
counter=0
for file in *; do 
    [[ -f $file ]] && echo mv -i "$file" $((counter+1)).png && ((counter++))
done
```

Here looping over all the files in the current directory and renaming sequentially based on order, if you want to deal with only the `.png` files, use `for file in *.png` instead. `counter` variable will keep track of the increments.

This is a dry-run, remove `echo` to let the actual renaming action take place.

**Example:**

```
$ counter=0; for file in *; do [[ -f $file ]] && echo mv -i "$file" $((counter+1)).png && ((counter++)); done
mv -i file.txt 1.png
mv -i foo.sh 2.png
mv -i bar.txt 3.png
```

Comment: You should put quotes around `$file` to avoid breaking on spaces, and put `((counter++))` inside an `if` statement to avoid incrementing on directories.

Comment: @wjandrea You don't need to quote when using `bash` keyword `[[` (unlike `[`), `[[` is a keyword, `bash` handles it internally as well as the word splitting and filename expansion too, hence no quoting needed. You're right about the second one, forgot that.  Edited..thanks..

Comment: Don't forget to check whether any of your destination filenames already exists in the directory. Suppose you run the script once, add a few files, and then try to run it again. What happens?

Comment: @DaveTweed that's what the `-i` option of `mv` will do..

Comment: *What* is what the `-i` option does? Even if you skip overwriting a file, you still won't end up with the correct result.

Comment: @DaveTweed Ahhh..i see what you meant. That would need a hash and some preprocessing..this answer is necessarily an one go..

Comment: In case somebody wants the result to be zero-padded, you can use `counter=0; for file in *; do [[ -f $file ]] && echo mv -i "$file" $(printf %03d $((counter+1))).png && ((counter++)); done`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a small python script that can do what you ask

Basic usage:

```
python rename_files.py Pictures/
```

It will print output to `stdout` before renaming each file

This version pushes index until it is found that filename with such index is not taken. Although filenames may start at different index upon successive iterations of the script, the files themselves remain unchanged.

```py
import os
import sys

top_dir = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])
files = os.listdir( top_dir )

for index,item in enumerate(files):
    if os.path.isdir( os.path.join(top_dir,item) ):
       files.pop(index)

files.sort()

duplicates = []
last_index = None
for index,item in enumerate(files):

    last_index = index
    extension = ""
    if '.' in item:
        extension = '.' + item.split('.')[-1]
    old_file = os.path.join(top_dir,item)
    new_file = os.path.join(top_dir,str(index) + extension  )
    while os.path.isfile(new_file):
          last_index += 1
          new_file = os.path.join(top_dir,str(last_index) + extension  )
    print( old_file + ' renamed to ' + new_file ) 
    os.rename(old_file,new_file)
```

Alternative version, solves issue with duplicate filenames by appending timestamp to each filename, and then enumerating them. This solution may take longer time, as number of files increases, but for directories that range in hundreds , this won't take long time

```py
import os
import sys
import time

top_dir = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])
files = os.listdir( top_dir )

for index,item in enumerate(files):
    if os.path.isdir( os.path.join(top_dir,item) ):
       files.pop(index)

files.sort()
timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
for item in files:
    os.rename( os.path.join(top_dir,item) ,
               os.path.join(top_dir, timestamp + item) )

files2 = os.listdir( top_dir )

for index,item in enumerate(files2):
    if os.path.isdir( os.path.join(top_dir,item) ):
       files2.pop(index)

for index,item in enumerate( files2  ):

    last_index = index
    extension = ""
    if '.' in item:
        extension = '.' + item.split('.')[-1]
    old_file = os.path.join(top_dir,item)
    new_file = os.path.join(top_dir,str(index) + extension  )

    while os.path.isfile(new_file):
          last_index += 1
          new_file = os.path.join(top_dir,str(last_index) + extension  )
    print( old_file + ' renamed to ' + new_file ) 
    os.rename(old_file,new_file)
```

Comment: Don't forget to check whether any of your destination filenames already exists in the directory. Suppose you run the script once, add a few files, and then try to run it again. What happens?

Comment: @DaveTweed can you provide an example ? running script twice wouldn't  have issue with duplicates, because entries are sorted and enumerated each time. So if 1.png already exists, it would get sorted and renamed to 1.png again

Comment: Suppose I run the script to produce `1.png` through `10.png`. Then I add the file `3a.png`, which should be renamed to `4.png`, which already exists -- not to mention the renaming all of the files after that.

Comment: Note that just having `1.png` through `10.png` by itself is a problem -- on the second run, you'll want to rename `10.png` to `2.png`, creating the same problem.

Comment: @DaveTweed is this the case you mean ? http://paste.ubuntu.com/22518702/

Comment: Also, how's this ? http://paste.ubuntu.com/22518907/

Comment: I get what you're saying, but do you have any suggestion on how to avoid overwriting duplicates ?

Comment: There are two issues here. The first is producing a sequence of output filenames that sorts to the same sequence when read as input. The second issue is the problem of overwriting an existing file.The latter must be addressed by forming a complete mapping from input names to output names, and then before you rename any files, you check for any collisions between the two lists. If any are found, they form "chains" of two or more names that must be handled last-first. I.e., you must rename `4.png` to `5.png` *before* you try to rename `3a.png` to `4.png`, and so forth.

Comment: ... This is the difference between "software engineering" and simple hacking.

Comment: @DaveTweed OK , I've edited my script somewhat to push index until there's no index that exists. Please check this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/22526386/ Updated script is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/22526509/

Comment: Here's one more with extensions http://paste.ubuntu.com/22526962/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43580/discussion-between-serg-and-dave-tweed).