# How to rename multiple files that have different names to file1, file2, file3, etc?

Tags: command-line, bash, rename, batch-rename

Let's say I have these files in my folder:

```
cat.txt
dog.txt
house.txt
tree.txt
```

I want to rename all of them to something like this:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
```

Is that possible to do via the command line?

I've only seen questions about renaming files that have some kind of pattern, like rename `dog1.txt`, `dog2.txt` -> `cat1.txt`, `cat2.txt`.

Comment: You can do it with a for i in *txt do; use a loop as a counter ; mv $1 file"$j".txt ;

Comment: http://alvinalexander.com/linux-unix/linux-shell-script-counter-math-addition-loop =)

Comment: See also [Rename all files in a folder to consecutive numbers](https://askubuntu.com/a/809017/178692) (just need to prepend `file`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `rename` utility to do this:

```
rename -n '$_ = sprintf "file%d.txt", ++$::count' *
```

#### Notes

- `-n` makes the command show you what will happen if you run it. If the output was what you  want, run it without `-n` to actually rename the files.
- replace the `*` with what you want to rename, for example: `dog*.txt` to only rename `dog1.txt`, `dog2.txt` ... to `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, etc.
- `$_` is a default input (file names) which we should modify.
- using `=` we are modifying it
- with `sprintf` we are defining a schema started by `file` followed by `%d` means a number and ended to the `.txt`.
- the number (%d) will be assigned using `++$::count`, which is a simple counter iterated after each rename.

*The idea comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257032/perls-rename-how-to-append-a-counter).*

Comment: It worked! Thank you. It was the simplest method I've seen. Well, I'm not a developer guy, so could you explain a little the part -> '$_ = sprintf "file%d.txt", ++$::count' ?

What I understand is the files will be renamed like file1, file2 etc because of the "file%d.txt", but the rest of the code I'm trying to understand. Thanks.

Comment: @DenisAlves Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It *may be* done, but with some caveats.  You have stated that "...these files [are] in my folder", which would be one of such caveats. We could use `globstar` and iterate over the expanded filenames:

```
$ c=0;for f in *; do ((c++));  echo "$f" "--->" file"$c".txt ; done                            
cat.txt ---> file1.txt
dog.txt ---> file2.txt
house.txt ---> file3.txt
tree.txt ---> file4.txt
```

Of course you could always go the "manual" way via a `list.txt`, where you can store a list of filenames and read that file via the `while IFS= read -r ; do ... done < list.txt`

```
$ c=0; while IFS= read -r f; do ((c++)); echo "$f" file"$c" ; done < input.txt                 
cat.txt file1
dog.txt file2
tree.txt file3
```

Of course this list theme can be extended in many ways - csv lists, json files,key-value lists - you name it.  There's plenty of questions about these online.  There's of course other choices you have to make, like give full path to files or perform everything in the same directory as the list.

Finally, I already hinted at key-value lists. With `bash` and other more modern scripting languages like Python or Perl, you could have a hash ( or dictionary ) with list of files and corresponding new name that you wish the file to have.